# Feature request: Combine log and activities when merging double contacts

Tags: activities, duplicate-contacts, logs

When contacts are merged, only the log and activities of one of the contacts are kept. Part of the change history is deleted and this is not always the right way, e.g. for auditing purposes.

It would be great to have an option when merging.

Comment: If audit trail is desired then consider turning on [trigger-based logging](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/logging/) as an alternate.

Comment: Merging two contacts should result in the saved contact ending up with both sets of Activities - have tested and confirmed this is working as expected on dmaster

Answer (score 0):

Just adding 'for the record' but not necessarily as an Answer to the core question.

Merging two contacts should result in the saved contact ending up with both sets of Activities (unless that option has been unchecked) - have tested and confirmed this is working as expected on dmaster

Contact A
[image]

Contact B
[image]

Merge screen
[image]

Outcome on Contact that is saved
[image]

The above assumes the Activities are not related to Cases.

Comment: I think the author meant civicrm_log entries, i.e. the changelog.

Comment: ah sorry 'activities' not Activities - well since this has some nice pictures maybe I will leave for a bit before destroying :-)

Comment: Hehe. I guess it's also possible that they did mean Activities, and that for whatever reason the checkbox on the "Activities" row on the merge screen was unchecked by default and they didn't check it. Since then it wouldn't copy over the Activities.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did mean log entries. Activities are merged as you said.

I will check the trigger-based logging, but I think that it is more for admins. I would like to see which changes a contact and its memberships have had.

The use case is that a person could be entered by different group admins, which are not aware of the mutual existence. When deduplicating, it would be great to have the changes combined.